# Outputting SVG Graph from D3.js Using Phantomjs

Tags: javascript, d3.js, phantomjs

I'm trying to render a force directed D3.js graph on the server side (because of the size of the dataset used) and output it as an a set of coordinates of the stable state of the graph i.e. when most of the heavy force calculations have been completed. For now I'm using an XMLSerlaizer.

Whenever I run the page from the command line using phantomjs it's almost like the  function that calls the graph drawing is never used. I thought this could be because of a missing `page.onConsoleMessage` which I added in but still the only output I get the console messages outside the function I wish to evaluate.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.content = '<html><body></body></html>';

console.log("before");

page.includeJs('https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js', function() {


    page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
        console.log("Message:" + msg);
    };


    console.log("p");

    var html = page.evaluate(function() {
        var body = d3.select('body');

        var data = {
                "nodes":[
                        {"name":"Steve"},
                        {"name":"Dave"},
                        {"name":"Matt"},
                        ],
                "links":
                        [{"source":0, "target":1},
                        {"source":1, "target":2},
                        {"source":2, "target":0}
                        ]
                    }


        var force = d3.layout.force()
                .charge(-140)
                .linkDistance(2)
                .size([500, 500])
                .nodes(data.nodes)
                .links(data.links)
                .start();

        var svg = body.
                .append('svg')
                .attr("width", 500)
                .attr("height", 500)
                .attr("id", "svg");
        ...
        ...Graph drawing code
        ...


        var s = new XMLSerializer();
        return s.serializeToString(document.querySelector('svg'));
    });
console.log(html);
console.log(page.content);
phantom.exit();   //Never gets called, "after" is printed
});

console.log("after");
phantom.exit();
```

So my question is, how do I run and output the values of the graph drawing function inside `page.includeJs...`?

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

***EDIT***

If I remove the surrounding `page.includeJs('https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js', function() {});` I get console messages up until the point where this javascript needs to be included. How can I include d3.js without doing it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by removing the surrounding `page.includeJs` block and replaced with `page.injectJs('d3.v3.min.js');`